# Erdös theorem which gives a weaker lower bound for R(k,k)

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I  have proved the theorem of Erdös that gives a lower bound for $R(k,k)$ and it is exponential in k. I have used probabilistic method to find this lower bound: $R(k,k) > (1+o(1))\frac {k}{(e√2)} √(2^k )$.

My question is: How can we construct a family of graphs that show this : $R(k,k) ≥ (k-1)^2$

I know that this is a weaker lower bound, but how to prove it?

I checked this link: [Lower bound for the Ramsey number $r(k,k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474650/lower-bound-for-the-ramsey-number-rk-k?answertab=active#tab-top) but still I am missing some details to understand the hint that is given in this link.

If someone could help me, I would appreciate it :)

Comment: What about the answer you've linked to don't you understand, exactly? If you don't say this, the most anyone can do is give that same answer again in different words.

Comment: we take $k−1$ disjoint (k−1)-cliques (i.e., complete subgraphs).

By definition, this graph has no k-cliques.

The complement of this graph is the complete (k−1)-partite graph $K_{k−1,k−1,…,k−1}$.
Now we need to argue that any k-vertex induced subgraph of this graph is not a clique and this is based on the Pigeonhole Principle. But I do not know how to write this last part

Comment: Did you mean $R(k,k)\gt(k-1)^2$? Was $\ge$ a typo?

Comment: No, ' ≥ ' wasn't a typo.

Comment: OK, but the question you linked to is about the strict inequality $R(k,k)\gt(k-1)^2$, and the obvious proof (as given in answers to that old question or the answer below) proves the strict inequality, so I wonder why you changed it to $\ge$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ is the union of $k-1$ disjoint $(k-1)$-cliques, so that $\overline{G}$ is the complete $(k-1)$-partite graph $K_{k-1,k-1,\dots,k-1}$.

Another way to say this is that $V(G) = V(\overline{G})$ is partitioned into $k-1$ sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_{k-1}$ of size $k-1$. Two vertices are adjacent in $G$ if they're in the same set, and they're adjacent in $\overline{G}$ if they're in different sets.

Now suppose that we pick any $k$ distinct vertices.

1. They cannot all be in the same set, because each set only has size $k-1$, and we are picking $k>k-1$ vertices. So at least two of them are in different sets - and those two vertices are not adjacent in $G$. Therefore $G$ does not have a clique of size $k$.
2. By the pigeonhole principle, since we have $k$ vertices and each of them is in one of the $k-1$ sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_{k-1}$, two vertices must be in the same set. Those two vertices are not adjacent in $\overline{G}$. Therefore $\overline{G}$ does not have a clique of size $k$.

Comment: Thaaank you for your response, it got clear now :)